# Definition of locally pathwise connected

Tags: general-topology

I have two definition of this property.

> *Def 1:* A space X is said to be locally path connected at x if for every (open) neighborhood U of x, there is a path-connected (open) neighborhood V of x contained in U. If X is locally path connected at each of its points, then it is said to be locally path connected.

*Munkres, Topology*

> *Def 2:* A space X is locally pathwise connected if each point has a nhood base consisting of pathwise connected sets.

*Willard, General Topology*

Notice, Def 1 is speaks of an **open** neighborhood, Def 2 of a generic neighborhood.

Are the two definition equivalent, if not which one is preferable?

Comment: These two don't seem to be equivalent in general (although I do not have any example). I think that Def 1 is used most of the time. Actually I strongly believe that this is a mistake (or missing assumption) in Willard's book. One reason is that Def 1 implies that (path) connected components are open. I don't see how this follows from Def 2. It just seems that Def 1 is more useful.

Comment: If X satisfies Def 2 it is easy to show that the pathwise-connected components of an open set are open, and so every point has a nbhd basis of open pathwise-connected sets.  However, Def 1 implies that the "open" is optional when referring to local pathwise-connectedness at a single point, and I can't see how to prove that.

Comment: @freakish As written above, def 2 is only given for the whole space.  But one can give a corresponding def at a specific point, in which case $X$ is called "path connected im kleinen" at the particular point.  This is a weaker notion than "locally path connected" at a point.  But if a space is path connected im kleinen at all points, it is locally path connected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Munkres regards all neighborhoods as open (see the definition on p.91). I do not know whether Willard has the same understanding of neighborhoods, but if so, then both definitions are obviously equivalent because a neigborhood base of $x \in X$ is a collection $\mathcal{U}$ of neigborhoods of $x$ such that each neigborhood $V$ of $x$ contains some $U \in \mathcal{U}$.

Added: I just read the proof of Theorem 25.3 in Munkres which can be "copied" to obtain a proof of Theorem 25.4.

The proof shows that the same results are true if we understand a neighborhood of $x$ to be any set $N$ such that $x \in \text{int}(N)$. In fact, look at the first part of proof. Then we get $x  \in \text{int}(V) \subset V \subset C$ which suffices to see that $C$ is open.

Comment: Willard does not assume neighborhoods to be open.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more general result.

Let us understand a neighborhood of $x$ to be any set $V$ such that $x \in \text{int}(V)$.

A space $X$ is said be *locally $0$-connected*, written as $LC^0$, if for each $x \in X$ and each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exists a neigborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V \subset U$ and such that for each $y \in V$ there exist a path in $U$ connecting $x$ and $y$.

See for example Chapter IV 8.13 in

Dold, Albrecht. Lectures on algebraic topology. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

$LC^0$ **seems** to be weaker than locally path connected because in the above definition the path connecting $x$ and $y$ is not required to stay in $V$. However

Theorem. The following are equivalent:

(1) All path components of open sets are open.

(2) Each $x \in X$ has a neighborhood base consisting of pathwise connected open sets. [Munkres]

(3) Each $x \in X$ has a neighborhood base consisting of pathwise connected sets. [Willard]

(4) $X$ is $LC^0$.

(5) For each $x \in X$ and each neighborhood $U$ of $x$, the path component of $x$ in $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Proof. (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2) : Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x \in X$ and let $C$ be the path component of $U$ containing $x$. But $U$ is open, hence (2) is satisfied.

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (3) $\Rightarrow$ (4) : This is obviuos.

(4) $\Rightarrow$ (5) : Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x \in X$ and $C$ be the path component of $U$ which contains $x$. Choose a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V \subset U$ and such that for each $y \in V$ there exists a path in $U$ connecting $x$ and $y$. Then clearly $y \in C$. Hence $V \subset C$.

(5) $\Rightarrow$ (1) : This is obvious.

Note that we could define variants of $LC^0$ by requiring one or both of $U,V$ to be open. The above proof is valid for all these variants, therefore they are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

As shown in my comment, the two definitions are equivalent for local pathwise-connectedness of the whole space. The corresponding definitions for local pathwise connectedness at a point are *not* equivalent. The example given here [Consider the "infinite broom"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439096/consider-the-infinite-broom) works for  local pathwise connectedness as well as local connectedness.  In that context, the definition including "open" is preferable.