# Local Path Connectedness - Collection Of All Path Connected Open Sets Is A Basis

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> A space $X$ is **locally path connected** if $X$ has a basis of path connected open sets.

A follow-up to this question:

[Hatcher Universal Covering Space Construction - Basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032962/hatcher-universal-covering-space-construction-basis)

From this definition, $X$ just has a basis of *some* collection of path connected open sets. Why can we actually take *all* path connected open sets to be a basis for $X$ when $X$ is locally path connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis for a given topology is just a collection of open sets $B$ such that every open set is a union of elements of $B$.  This will remain true if you add more open sets to $B$.  So, any collection of open sets which contains a basis is itself a basis.