# Let $S$ be an open connected set in $\Bbb R^n$, let $T$ be a component of $\Bbb R^n-S$. Prove that $\Bbb R^n-T$ is connected

Tags: calculus, connectedness

$\Bbb R^n-S=T\cup (\bigcup A)$, $T$ and these $A$ are components in $\Bbb R^n-S$.

$\Bbb R^n-T=S\cup(\bigcup A)$,

$\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}$
since $\partial S \subseteq \Bbb R^n-S,\partial S\subseteq (\bigcup A)$

I consider $S\cup \partial S \cup (\bigcup A)=\bigcup (\cl S \cup A)$

If $S$ is not an empty set, and if for every $A$, $\cl S \cup A$ is connected, in that way, $\Bbb R^n-T$ is connected.

Closure of $S$ is connected, every $A$ is connected,if $\cl S\cap A$ is not empty set, in that way, $\cl  S\cup A $ is connected.

**But I can’t prove $\cl  S\cap A $ is not the empty set. Could you give me some hints or other methods different from mine to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance**

> The definition of component
>
> every metric space $S$ can be expressed in a unique way as a union of connected "pieces" called components.

Sorry, I found a mistake of my method, $\partial A\subseteq \bigcup A\cup T$, and my method is wrong now.

Comment: What is the context of your question? Is it an exercise in general topology?

Comment: It’s an exercise in Tom Apostol mathematical analysis page100,exercise 4.48

Comment: @PaulFrost,what do you think this problem?Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Can you show that $T$ is closed and that $S\cup T$ is open? Then if $U,V$ cover $\Bbb R^n-T$, one of them, $U$ say,  contains $S$. Replace $U$ with $U\cup T$ and $V$ with $V-T$ and use that $\Bbb R^n$ is connected

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen T is closed in $R^n-S$ because T is a component of $R^n-S$,but T is not always closed in $R^n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen An essential ingredient is that $\mathbb R^n$ is locally connected.

Comment: $T$ is always closed in $\mathbb R^n$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}$

Let $A = \mathbb R^n \setminus S$ which is closed in $\mathbb R^n$. All components $C_\iota$ of $A$ are closed in $A$, hence closed in $\mathbb R^n$.

The cases $S = \emptyset, \mathbb R^n$ are trivial, so let us assume $\emptyset \ne S \ne \mathbb R^n$. Then we have $S \subsetneqq \cl S$ because otherwise $S$ would be open and closed in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $S = \emptyset$ or $S = \mathbb R^n$ since  $\mathbb R^n$ is connected. Thus $\cl S \cap A \ne \emptyset$.

We have $\cl S \cap C_\iota \ne \emptyset$ for all components of $A$. Assume that $\cl S \cap C_\iota = \emptyset$ for some $\iota$. Then $C_\iota$ must be a component of $B = \mathbb R^n \setminus \cl S$. To see this, let $D$ be the component of $B$ containing $C_\iota$. Then $D$ is a connected subset of $A \supset B$ and therefore contained in a component $C_{\iota'}$ of $A$. We have $C_\iota  \subset D \subset C_{\iota'}$ which implies $\iota' = \iota$. But now $B$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, hence *locally connected*, and this implies that $C_{\iota}$ is open in $B$, hence open in  $\mathbb R^n$. Concerning *local connectedness* see my answer to [About local linear connect](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3048034). We have seen that $C_\iota$ is open and closed in $\mathbb R^n$, hence either $C_\iota = \emptyset$ or $C_\iota =\mathbb R^n$. Both is impossible and our assumption  must be false.

We have $\mathbb R^n \setminus T = S  \cup \bigcup_{\iota \in I} C_\iota$, where $I$ contains all $\iota$ such that $C_\iota \ne T$. For each $\iota \in I$ pick $x_\iota \in \cl S$ such that $x_\iota \in C_\iota$. Then $S' = S \cup \{x_\iota \mid \iota \in I \}$ is connected because $S \subset S' \subset \cl S$. But now
$$\mathbb R^n \setminus T = S'  \cup \bigcup_{\iota \in I} C_\iota$$
This show that  $\mathbb R^n \setminus T$ is connected because all $S' \cap C_\iota \ne \emptyset$.

**Remark.**

In this proof one can replace $\mathbb R^n$ by any space $X$ which is connected and locally connected.