# $Y$ relatively compact in non-cpct riemann surface $X$. Choose domain $Y_1\subset X$ s.t. $Y_1$ relatively cpct in $X$ and $Y$ relatively cpct in $Y$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-compact riemann surface and $Y$ relatively compact open subset of $X$. The book says "Choose domain $Y_1$ s.t. $Y\subset Y_1\subset X$ and a point $a\in Y_1-Y$.(Since $X$ is non-compact and connected, $Y_1-Y$ is non-empty.)"

$\textbf{Q:}$ The following is my thought process. Since $Y$ is relatively compact, there can only be finite number of path components. Since $Y\subset X$ and $X$ is connected, $X$ is path connected. So connect path components of $\bar{Y}$ by path and add tubular neighborhood of those path s.t. it locally looks like product of intervals. Use those tubular neighborhood and original $\bar{Y}$ to form $Y_1$. Clearly $Y_1$ is relatively compact in $X$ and $Y$ is relatively compact in $Y_1$. Furthermore $Y_1-Y$ is non-empty as I need to add extra points away from $\bar{Y}$. How should I interpret the statement? How to choose domain $Y_1$ and show there is a point $a\in Y_1-Y$? It seems the book says this is supposed to be obvious.

Ref. Forster Lectures on Riemann Surface Chpt 14, Cor 14.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say it is obvious.

You have correctly shown that $Y$ is contained in a compact path connected set $C$. Now choose a relatively compact open neighborhhod $U$ of $C$. Riemann surfaces are locally path connected (i.e. have a base consisting of path connected open sets). In locally connected path spaces the path components of open sets are open. See the answers to [Definition of locally pathwise connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2999685).

Now let $Y_1$ be the path component of $U$ containing the path connected $C$. Clearly $Y_1 \subset \overline{U} \ne X$.

Edited:

I was wrong when I said that you have correctly shown that $Y$ is contained in a compact path connected set $C$. The statement ist true, but your argument was that a relatively compact set can only have a finite number of path components. Here is a counterexample: Let $Y \subset \mathbb{C}$ be the set of all $z$ such that $\text{Im} z \in (0,1)$ and $\text{Re} z \in (0,1) \setminus \{ 1/n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

So let us give a complete proof. We assume that $X$ is a path connected topological space such that each point has a path connected open neighborhood $U$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact and path connected. Each Riemann surfaces has this property (take suitable disks around the points).

(1) Each relatively compact $Y \subset X$ is contained in a path connected compact $C \subset X$.

$\overline{Y}$ is covered by path connected open sets $U$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact. Choose a finite subcover $U_0,\dots,U_n$. Choose paths $u_i$ connecting $U_0$ and $U_i$ for $i =1,\dots,n$. Then $C = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \overline{U_i} \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^n u_i([0,1])$ will do.

(2) Each compact path connected $C \subset X$ has a relatively compact path connected open neighborhood $Y'$.

$C$ is covered by finitely many path connected open sets $V_j$ such that $V_j \cap C \ne \emptyset$ and $\overline{V_j}$ is compact. Then $Y' = \bigcup_j V_j = C \cup \bigcup_j V_j$ will do.