# why together with the interval $(1/2, 1]$ on the x-axis?

Tags: general-topology

Definition of Infinite Broom

In [wikipidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_broom#:%7E:text=In%20topology%2C%20a%20branch%20of,to%20as%20the%20broom%20space)  it is written  that

> The infinite broom is the subset of the Euclidean plane that consists of all closed line segments joining the origin to the point $(1, 1/n)$ as n varies over all positive integers, together with the interval $(1/2, 1]$ on the x-axis

Diagram of infinite broom

[image]

**My thinking** : From the diagram ,we conclude that all the line segment  start  from  $(0,0)$  to  $(1,1/n)$ and there is no any  line segment  start  from $(1/2,1]$

I  don't understand this sentence **together  with the interval $(1/2,1$]  on the $x$  axis**

why together with the interval $(1/2, 1]$ on the x-axis ?

Comment: The infinite broom is an example similar to that of the topologist's sine curve which is connected but not path connected. The interval $\left(\frac12,1\right]$ ensures that it isn't path connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra $(\frac12,1] \times \{0\}$ makes it a better counterexample to some common ideas: it's connected but not path-connected and not locally (path-)connected at the $x$-axis points either. It's its raison d'être, as it were. It's similar to the topologist's sine curve (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), e.g.) in that respect.