# weakly locally connected in infinitebroom

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Consider the "infinite broom" $X$ pictured in figure below. Show that $X$  is [weakly connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438916/weakly-locally-connected) at $p$.
>
> [image: infinite broom]

My attempt : I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2440264/557708).But im not satisfied with answer

**My attempt** :  Consider  $X$ to be a  subspace  of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $p=(0,0) $ and each $a_n$ on the positive  $x-$ axis .Let us  assume $V$ as an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $U$ be an open neighbhood  of $p$

By the definition of  subspace topology  $U= X \cap V $ is open/closed. This implies  $V$  contains  an open ball $B(p,a_n)$.

Now take  connected subspace  $Y$  of  $X$  where  $Y=  U'\cup \{a_{n+1}\}$ because $U' \cap a_{n+1}  \neq  \emptyset$  where $U'=X \setminus B(p,a_{n+1})$

Therefore $Y \subset U$ and contains the neighbhorhood  $X \cap B(p,a_{n+1})$ of $p$

Now  by the Munkres book definition $X$  is weakly locally connected at $p$

**A space $X$ is said to be weakly locally connected at $x$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a connected subspace of $Y$ contained in $U$ that contains a neighborhood of $x.$**

Note : Take  $x=p$

Is  my proof is correct or not ?

Comment: I am more satisfied with the linked argument. You pick $V$ and $U$ and then say that $U=X\setminus V$. If the $V,U$ were chosen already, they could have been chosen without that property. The choice of $V$ must be made dependent on $U$. You probably want $X\cap V$ rather than $X\setminus V$. The $n$ in the next sentence hasn't been defined.

Comment: @plop you are  right it should be $X\cap V$ . But linked argument  doesn't follow  the Munkres definition .

Comment: It does prove the same. They produce a connected subspace $Y$ that is contained in the given neighborhood $U$, contains $p$, and contains a neighborhood of $p$. The neighborhood of $p$ that it contains is the interior of $Y$.

Comment: @plop that argument say that the subspace of $X$ including $p$ and every broom until the $n$th-one that mean it is a straight  line  from point $p$ to $a_n=[p,a_n]$  which is not open but closed set  . we know  that  interior $[p,a_n] =(p,a_n)$  doesn't contains p i,e interior doesn't contains point $p$

Comment: When I read "broom" in that sentence I understood not just the segments $[a_{n+1},a_n]$, but also the other little segments that depart from $a_n$.

Comment: okss  @plop  that  mean subspace of $X$ including $p$ and every broom until the $n$th-one , $n>N$ are the intersection of  closed half plane  to the  left side of $a_n $ and $U$.So this space is obviously closed set and connected but not open .Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, the intersection of the closed half plane at $a_n$ and $X$. That intersection is a connected subspace of $X$, that contains $p$ in its interior, and $a_n$ was chosen such that it is included in $U$.

Comment: oks, thank u @plop . Now now I've understood it